# Vite.js: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fd')

Tags: reactjs, vite

When I try to run `npm run preview` after running `npm run build`, I see an error in the console of the browser:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fd')
    at Function.dt [as useColors] (index-CINUoA1E.js:80:6691)
    at Function.ct (index-CINUoA1E.js:66:100504)
    at new Logger$2 (index-CINUoA1E.js:84:1148)
    at index-CINUoA1E.js:84:2001
```

I've encountered this error previously while transitioning my project from webpack to vite. To fix it, I added some plugins to my `vite.config.js` file. However, when I previewed the build, the error resurfaced. I'm feeling stuck at the moment, and would appreciate any assistance.

```js
import { defineConfig, transformWithEsbuild } from "vite";
import { NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";
import { NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin } from "@esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill";
import rollupNodePolyFill from "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import path from "path";
import envCompatible from "vite-plugin-env-compatible";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig(() => {
  return {
    plugins: [
      {
        name: "treat-js-files-as-jsx",
        async transform(code, id) {
          if (!id.match(/src\/.*\.js$/)) return null;

          // Use the exposed transform from vite, instead of directly
          // transforming with esbuild
          return transformWithEsbuild(code, id, {
            loader: "jsx",
            jsx: "automatic",
          });
        },
      },
      envCompatible(),
      react(),
      svgr(),
    ],
    optimizeDeps: {
      force: true,
      esbuildOptions: {
        loader: {
          ".js": "jsx",
        },
        define: {
          global: "globalThis",
        },
        plugins: [
          NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin({
            process: true,
            // buffer: true,
          }),
          NodeModulesPolyfillPlugin(),
        ],
      },
    },
    define: {
      process: {},
    },
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        src: path.resolve("./src"),
        support: path.resolve(__dirname, "./cypress/support"),
        process: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/process-es6",
        stream: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/stream",
        tty: "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills/polyfills/tty",
        "plotly.js": "plotly.js-dist",
        // ...(process.env.isEnvProductionProfile && {
        //   "react-dom$": "react-dom/profiling",
        //   "scheduler/tracing": "scheduler/tracing-profiling",
        // }),
      },
      extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx", ".jsx"],
      mainFields: [],
    },
    server: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 3000,
      open: true,
    },
    build: {
      commonjsOptions: { transformMixedEsModules: true }, 
      rollupOptions: {
        plugins: [
          rollupNodePolyFill(),
        ],
      }
    },
    css: {
      preprocessorOptions: {
        less: {
          javascriptEnabled: true,
        },
      },
    },
  };
});
```